# Set height to be equal width minus some value

Tags: css

```
<div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="cta-item cta-1">
                <a href="#">
                    <div class="hover"><p>Serving food fine to fast. Come <span class="arrow">Hungry</span></p></div>
                    <p class="cta-title">Visit</p>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="cta-item cta-2">
                <a href="#">
                    <div class="hover"><p>Serving food fine to fast. Come <span class="arrow">Hungry</span></p></div>
                    <p class="cta-title">Shop</p>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="cta-item cta-3">
                <a href="#">
                    <div class="hover"><p>Serving food fine to fast. Come <span class="arrow">Hungry</span></p></div>
                    <p class="cta-title">Eat</p>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(cta);
$(window).resize(cta);

function cta() {
    var ctaWidth = $('.cta-item').width();
    var newHeight = ctaWidth - 40;

    $('.cta-item').css( 'height', newHeight );
}
</script>
```

My question is how to do height = width - 40px for particular element by pure css?

Thanks.

Comment: Consider using margins and paddings.

Comment: you can use `calc(100vh - 40px)` or `calc(100vw - 40px)`, if you want a calculative `height` or `width`

Comment: @vivekkupadhyay, but 100vh & 100vw are all about viewports. But my question is about width & hight of particular element.

Comment: then using pure **CSS**, there might not be any solution regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

If you need CSS to work in older browsers, too, there is a way utilizing the fact, that vertical padding is always calculated in relation to the parent element’s width. So you can do like this to enforce the height:

```
// additional styles when Bootstrap css is loaded
.cta-item {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #ffcccc;
  *zoom: 1;
}

.cta-item::before {
  width: 0;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  content: ' ';
  padding-bottom: 100%; /* makes height match width */
  margin-top: -40px; /* value substracted from height */
}
// clearfix
.cta-item::after {
  content: ' ';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/7m5vyaqs/1/

It works like a min-height. If you want it to be a max-height, you have to wrap the `.cta-item`’s contents into a container and position it absolute. Like:

```
.cta-item > *:first-child {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply. Could you please provide jsfiddle for the answer.

Comment: Thanks man for help. But are you sure it works?
I resize a browser window but nothing changes except divs goes each under each other.

Comment: Updated the example to be fluid and use Bootstrap styles. Should work now as expected until it reaches lower breakpoint. Give it a try.